# How to get number of half centuries, centuries and double hundreds for each player in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have table with this format

```
id| name | types |
_________________
 1   sachin   100
 2   virat    50
 3   sachin   50
 4   sachin   50
 5   sachin   200
 6   virat    100
 7   virat    200
```

What I want to get as the result is now something like

```
 name   | num of 50 |num of 100 |num of 200
 sachin |    2      |    1      | 1
 virat  |    1      |    1      | 1
```

What is the correct way to get here ??
I tried using group by. But I didn't get there

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: You can use pivots that would give you accurate result

Comment: refer this <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table>

Comment: @KRU Thanks. I wiil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just have these types, you can try this:

```
select
    name,
    count(case when types = 50 then 1 else null end) as num_50,
    count(case when types = 100 then 1 else null end) as num_100,
    count(case when types = 200 then 1 else null end) as num_200
from yourtable
group by name
```

[<kbd>Demo Here</kbd>](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/447ee9/1)

Comment: Thanks for the demo. I didn't need to recreate it :p

Comment: Yes . I have only 3 types

Comment: Make your debut by accepting the answer.  [**How to accept answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). It's a good practice indeed. @motabul

Answer (score 3):

Also you can rely on `MySQL` boolean expression.

```
SELECT
    name,
    SUM(types = 50) as num_50,
    SUM(types = 100) as num_100,
    SUM(types = 200) as num_200
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY name
```

**Note:**

Since MySQL boolean expression resolves into `0/1` so that you can use it inside `SUM()`

`SUM(a=b) returns 1 only if a is equal to b`

[**Working demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/447ee9/2/0)

**More:**

And if you use `COUNT` as mentioned in @JPG's answer then keep in mind the following subtleties of `COUNT`

**Some subtleties regarding `COUNT`:**

```
SELECT COUNT(0);   Result: 1

SELECT COUNT(-1);  Result: 1

SELECT COUNT(NULL); Result: 0

SELECT COUNT(71); Result: 1
```

[**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/68544/0)